# VBA How to select a range of rows relative to active cell?

Tags: vba

In VBA, I want to select a range of rows relative to the active cell.  For example, select rows +3 to +5 relative to the active cell.  I tried the following without success:

`Rows(ActiveCell.Row+3:ActiveCell.Row+5).Select`

Comment: You rarely need to Select anything but you can use the `Resize` method.

Comment: Try `ActiveCell.Offset(3).EntireRow.Resize(3).Select`. The latter `3` derives from `5 - 3 + 1`. Your idea would be `Rows(ActiveCell.Row + 3 & ":" & ActiveCell.Row + 5).Select`.

Comment: VBasic2008:  Your answer solved the problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ActiveCellNewRange()
 Dim rngArea As Range
 
 'set new range
 Set rngArea = Sheet1.Range("C5").Offset(3).EntireRow.Resize(5)
 
 'Select and write to immeadiate window
 rngArea.Select
 Debug.Print rngArea.Address
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Why "C5"?  I don't understand the purpose of "C5".  I wanted to select rows +3 through +5 relative to the currently active cell.  For example, if active cell is B3, then I want to select rows 6,7,8.